# Why does a parsed double not equal an initialized double supposedly of the same value?

Tags: c#, math, double, mspec

When I execute this line:

```
double dParsed = double.Parse("0.00000002036");
```

dParsed actually gets the value: 0.000000020360000000000002

Compared to this line,

```
double dInitialized = 0.00000002036;
```

in which case the value of dInitialized is exactly 0.00000002036

Here they are in the debugger:
[image: Difference between double.Parse and an initializer]

This inconsistency is a trifle annoying, because I want to run tests along the lines of:

```
[Subject("parsing doubles")]
public class when_parsing_crazy_doubles
    {
    static double dInitialized = 0.00000002036;
    static double dParsed;
    Because of = () => dParsed = double.Parse("0.00000002036");
    It should_match = () =>  dParsed.ShouldBeLike(dInitialized);
    }
```

This of course fails with:

```
Machine.Specifications.SpecificationException
"":
  Expected: [2.036E-08]
  But was:  [2.036E-08]
```

In my production code, the 'parsed' doubles are read from a data file whereas the comparison values are hard coded as object initializers. Over many hundreds of records, 4 or 5 of them don't match. The original data appears in the text file like this:

> 0.00000002036 0.90908165072    6256.77753019160

So the values being parsed have only 11 decimal places. Any ideas for working around this inconsistency?

While I accept that comparing doubles for equality is risky, I'm surprised that the compiler can get an exact representation when the text is used as an object initializer, but that double.Parse can't get an exact representation when parsing exactly the same text. How can I limit the parsed doubles to 11 decimal places?

Comment: Note that `0.00000002036` is really 2.035999999999999834810563976821018439267163557815365493297576904296875e-08 and `0.000000020360000000000002` is really 2.0360000000000001656828089980320883878306403858005069196224212646484375e-08.  The difference between the two is exactly 2^(-78).

Comment: In other words, the compiler's representation is not exact. Tim Long, notice how close 2.036e-8 is to being exactly in the middle of those two numbers dan04 printed. The first number is a tiny, tiny bit closer to 2.036e-8 than is the second value. Your compiler's conversion algorithm got it right, where "right" means "within half an ULP". The compiled binary representation is (just barely) within half an ULP of that from an infinite precision machine. The parser didn't quite get it right; the parsed representation is (just barely) more than half an ULP from the infinite precision value.

Comment: Apparently the compiler and parser use two different implementations.  for the curious, there is a great site on floating point numbers: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: What this means is that your compiler and your input library are using different parsing algorithms. The numbers that are just on the cusp of rounding up versus rounding down are always going to be a bit problematic. The goal is to make the error be half an ULP or less. That's a goal. The reality is that that goal is not always achieved. There are always going to be nasty corner cases where the conversion gets it wrong, but hopefully only by a tiny bit.

Answer (score 4):

> Compared to this line,

```
double dInitialized = 0.00000002036;
```

> in which case the value of dInitialized is exactly 0.00000002036

If you have anything remotely resembling a commodity computer, `dInitialized` is *not* initialized as exactly 0.00000002036. It can't be because the base 10 number 0.00000002036 does not have a finite representation in base 2.

Your mistake is expecting two doubles to compare equal. That's usually not a good idea. Unless you have very good reasons and know what you are doing, it is best to not compare two doubles for equality or inequality. Instead test whether the difference between the two lies within some small epsilon of zero.

Getting the size of that epsilon right is a bit tricky. If your two numbers are both small, (less than one, for example), an epsilon of 1e-15 might well be appropriate. If the numbers are large (larger than ten, for example), that small of an epsilon value is equivalent to testing for equality.

**Edit:** I didn't answer the question.

> How can I limit the parsed doubles to 11 decimal places?

If you don't have to worry about very small values,

```
static double epsilon = 1e-11;
if (Math.Abs(dParsed-dInitialized) > epsilon*Math.Abs(dInitialized)) {
    noteTestAsFailed();
}
```

You should be able to safely change that `epsilon` to 4e-16.

**Edit #2:** *Why is it that the compiler and `double.Parse` produce different internal representations for the same text?*

That's kind of obvious, isn't it? The compiler and `double.Parse` use different algorithms. The number in question 0.00000002036 is very close to being on the cusp of whether rounding up or rounding down should be used to yield a representable value that is within half an ULP of the desired value (0.00000002036). The "right" value is the one that is within a half an ULP of the desired value. In this case, the compiler makes the right decision of picking the rounded-down value while the parser makes the wrong decision of picking the rounded-up value.

The value 0.00000002036 is a nasty corner case. It is not an exactly representable value. The two closest values that can be represented exactly as IEEE doubles are 6153432421838462/2^78 and 6153432421838463/2^78. The value halfway between these two is 12306864843676925/2^79, which is very, very close to 0.00000002036. That's what makes this a corner case. I suspect all of the values you found where the compiled value is not identically equal to the value from `double.Parse` are corner cases, cases where the desired value is almost halfway between the two closest exactly representable values.

**Edit #3:**

Here are a number of different ways to interpret 0.00000002036:

- 2/1e8 + 3/1e10 + 6/1e11
- 2*1e-8 + 3*1e-10 + 6*1e-11
- 2.036 * 1e-8
- 2.036 / 1e8
- 2036 * 1e-11
- 2036 / 1e11

On an ideal computer all of these will be the same. Don't count on that being the case on a computer that uses finite precision arithmetic.

Comment: Of note: while C# defines `double.Epsilon`, the C# documentation notes that using it for comparing doubles for equality is not recommended. `double.Epsilon` is the smallest positive double value, and so it is only useful with values which are very-near-zero.

Comment: @David I expected someone to give that response, but that isn't really the point of my question. Clearly, the numbers are not equal because they are different. My question is, why is it that the compiler and double.Parse produce different internal representations for the same text? I'll update my question with a screen shot from the debugger showing the actual values.

Comment: Why the heck did Microsoft give the name `Epsilon` to something that has nothing to do with machine epsilon (2.220446049250313e-16)?  It's like defining `Math.PI` as 2.718281828459045.

Comment: MSpec has `x.ShouldBeCloseTo(value, epsilon)` to assert on floating point numbers.